# Why doesn't this lambda example from the MSDN site work?

Tags: c#, lambda

What do I have to do to the following lambda example to get it to work?

ERROR: *Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace TestLambda
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            delegate int del(int i);
            del myDelegate = x => x * x;
            int j = myDelegate(5); //j = 25
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: JaredPar has covered it; but note that MSDN samples are sometimes abbreviated. Arguably, an ellipsis would have been clearer here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare the delegate outside of the method:

```
class Program
{
    delegate int del(int i);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        del myDelegate = x => x * x;
        int j = myDelegate(5); //j = 25
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not legal to define a type as a method body statement in C#.  You'll need to move the delegate outside the method in order to get that to compile.  For example

```
    delegate int del(int i);

public static void Main(string[] args) {

    del myDelegate = x => x * x;
    int j = myDelegate(5); //j = 25
}
```

Comment: Or even better, just use Func<int,int> ;-p

Comment: @Marc, yes.  I think that if you could essentially typedef a Func<>,Action<> at an assembly level, it would go a long way to preventing people from creating new delegate types when a simple Func<>,Action<> would do.